# How to mask string after first character

Tags: c#, data-masking

Let's say I have a string that consists of a person's name:

```
var name = "Jason, Bruno Mars";
```

How do I mask the `string` with `X` for the name behind the comma and returns:

```
var name = "Jason, BXXXX MXXX";
```

I have tried using the following methods but only front characters are masked:

```
string first, second, output;
bool hasSpace, hasComma;
int int_LENGTH;
var name = "Jason, Bruno Mars";
hasComma = name.Contains(",");

if (hasComma == true)
{
    int_LENGTH = name.IndexOf(",");
    if (int_LENGTH > 0)
    {
        first = name.Substring(0, int_LENGTH);
    }

    second = string.Join(",", name.Split(" ").Skip(1));
    hasSpace = second.Contains(" ");

    if (hasSpace == true)
    {
        second = string.Concat(new string('X', 12), second.Substring(second.Length - 4));
        output = first + "," + second;
    }
}
```

Anyone has a better idea of how can I achieve the same result in a more efficient way?

Comment: It seems that you're actually trying to mask all of the characters after the first in each word, but excluding the first word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, using [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) to select the name parts except the first letter. The regex collects all string parts separated by a space, skipping what's before the comma.
The collections of `Matches` is then passed to Linq's [Aggregate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) method to perform the substitution.
A [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.-ctor) is used to store the strings generated by its own [Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace) method:

```
string theName = "Jason Et Alt., Bruno Mars And More Names";
var matches = Regex.Matches(theName, @"(?!.*?,)\s+?.(\w+)");

string outName = matches.OfType<Match>().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(theName), (sb, m) => 
   sb.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, new string('X', m.Groups[1].Length))).ToString();
```

```
outname = Jason Et Alt., BXXXX MXXX AXX MXXX NXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficient way of masking without `Split`, `Regex`, and `using System.Linq`:

**For C# version < 7.2:**

```
static string MaskName(string name)
{
    int indexOfComma = name.IndexOf(',');

    if (indexOfComma != -1)
    {
        char[] temp = name.ToCharArray();

        bool isFirstChar = true;

        for (int i = indexOfComma + 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == ' ')
                isFirstChar = true;
            else if (isFirstChar)
                isFirstChar = false;
            else
                temp[i] = 'X';
        }

        return new string(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**For C# version >= 7.2:**

```
static string MaskName(ReadOnlySpan<char> name)
{
    int indexOfComma = name.IndexOf(',');

    if (indexOfComma != -1)
    {
        Span<char> temp = stackalloc char[name.Length];

        name.CopyTo(temp);

        bool isFirstChar = true;

        for (int i = indexOfComma + 1; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == ' ')
                isFirstChar = true;
            else if (isFirstChar)
                isFirstChar = false;
            else
                temp[i] = 'X';
        }

        return new string(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        return name.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static string MaskName(string name)
    {
        string maskedString = string.Empty;

        string[] names = name.Split(',');
        if (names.Length > 0)
        {
            maskedString = names[0] + ",";
        }
        if (names.Length > 1)
        {
            string[] arrName = names[1].Split(' ');
            foreach (string s in arrName)
            {
                if (s.Length > 0)
                    maskedString += " " + s[0].ToString().PadRight(s.Length, 'X');
            }
        }
        return maskedString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using This code..

    static string MaskName(string name)
    {
        string maskedString = string.Empty;

        string[] names = name.Split(',');
        if (names.Length > 0)
        {
            maskedString = names[0] + ",";
        }
        if (names.Length > 1)
        {
            string[] arrName = names[1].Split(' ');
            foreach (string s in arrName)
            {
                if (s.Length > 0)
                    maskedString += " " + s[0].ToString().PadRight(s.Length, 'X');
            }
        }
        return maskedString;
    }
```

Output :-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 private string ReturnMaskedName(string name)
        {
            string temporary = "";
            var newname = (name.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim().Split(new String[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None));

            foreach (string allnames in newname)
            {
                temporary = temporary + " " + allnames[0].ToString() + new string('X', allnames.Length - 1);
            }
            return name.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + " " + temporary;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private string MaskName(string name)
{
    var parts = name.Split(',');
    var subparts = parts[1].Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (var i = 0; i < subparts.Length; i++)
    {
        var subpart = subparts[i];

        subparts[i] = subpart[0] + new string('X', subpart.Length - 1);
    }

    return parts[0] + ", " + string.Join(" ", subparts);
}
```